# Tools for Apache Cordova project build crashes in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

I have a copy of Visual Studio 2017 Professional and I downloaded the Tools for Apache Cordova. I created a new blank project, downloaded the JDK/JRE and the Android SDK tools and emulator.

Every time I hit the 'Build' or 'Deploy' button, the build appears to complete, then Visual Studio stalls - and remains this way until the process is terminated via task explorer. There are no other error messages or apparent build failures.

Any ideas why this would happen? I'm totally lost here.

Comment: This is not really a solution, but for anyone interested I've come to the conclusion that Microsoft aren't interested in their Tools For Apache Cordova any longer. I've since started an Ionic project (which uses Apache Cordova) using Visual Studio Code and things have been going smoothly.